# how to add custom tool chain to eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse

I have got a custom tool chain based on gnu arm. I have downloaded eclipse IDE with CDT. I would like to know how to add my tool chain with the eclipse. It has got a generic tool chain namely Linux GCC. Apart from that there is nothing. I would like to add mine.
I am not finding any set up window that helps me in that.
Thank you.

Krish.

Answer (score 18):

I'm sure this is far too late for you now but I thought I'd point anyone else in the direction of the [Managed Build System Extensibility Document](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv/guide/mbs/extensibilityGuide/Managed_Build_Extensibility.html).

There is a tutorial in that page that guides you through the steps involved in creating a basic toolchain. It certainly gave me a basic understanding of how toolchains are structured in Eclipse.

For more advanced queries you may want to try the [CDT Forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=80).

I hope this is of some help to someone.

Alan

Answer (score 1):

You may add your toolchain from the help of following Link http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_prop_build_toolchain.htm. The idea is to follow the code for the existing supported toolchains, add yours to the source code. Then [follow the project document to build it](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/gnuarmeclipse/index.php?title=How_to_build) and install the plug-in. This way you don't have to start from scratch.