# debugger for c++ using eclipse on mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, debugging

After I finally setup my mac to work with eclipse, I can't debug.

I've tried to google for help but non of the answers worked for me.

so, I need someone to help me install and use a debugger on eclipse for c\c++.

I have Xcode 5.0 installed.

Thanks for your help

Roy

Comment: Here is my solution

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877047/eclipse-gdb-macosx-mavericks

Answer (score 3):

You have got several options:

1. Install GDB with MacPorts or Homebrew, as mentioned by [trojanfoe](/a/19536455) and [Charles Chow](/a/23704065).
2. Use LLDB-MI from LLDB team; note that LLDB-MI does not come with the native LLDB on OS X, meaning you have to build LLDB your own with options to switch on the feature.
3. Use third-party [LLDB-MI2](https://github.com/freedib/lldbmi2) (see the page for reasons why he needs another Machine Interface)

All of these three options require a lot of configuration and are error-prone. I guess you may want to think twice when you prefer Eclipse to Xcode on OS X.

Answer (score 0):

[It looks like](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=405670) eclipse doesn't support `lldb`, so you are probably better off ignoring the Xcode toolchain and instead installing [Macports](http://www.macports.org/) and g++/gdb from there:

```
$ sudo port install gcc49 gdb
```

It should then just be a case of setting up this new toolchain in eclipse; perhaps using:

[how to add custom tool chain to eclipse CDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489607/how-to-add-custom-tool-chain-to-eclipse-cdt)

(if not google "eclipse cdt configure toolchain")

Comment: brew.io - much nicer interface than macports and it doesn't want root privileges to run

Comment: @Petesh Each to his own, but I prefer macports.

Comment: I cant find any tutorial explaining how to install macports on OSX mavericks.

Comment: @RoyWeinstein Ah, yeah that will be a problem as I don't believe they've released for Mavericks yet.  I run on my Mavericks using the "trunk" version of macports which works fine.  Check this: https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/RunningTrunk

Answer (score 0):

I found [this tutorial](http://ntraft.com/installing-gdb-on-os-x-mavericks/) teaches you how to install and setup GDB for eclipse on Mac OS X.
It works on my machine.  You need install [Home Brew](http://brew.sh/) first.