# debugging in eclipse using gdb on mac - Failed to execute MI command: -exec-run

Tags: c, eclipse, macos, debugging, gdb

I have my Eclipse Kepler and my simple HelloWorld C-program, where I wanted to learn how to debug a C-program. When clicking on the debug-button, I get the following error message:

Error in final launch sequence
Failed to execute MI command:
-exec-run
Error message from debugger back end:
Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 359: (os/kern) failure (0x5).
Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 359: (os/kern) failure (0x5).

I searched the whole day and didn't find any solution. I already did all of the recommended things in this post [Eclipse GDB MacOSX Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877047/eclipse-gdb-macosx-mavericks) and still get this error.

It would be really great, if somebody could help me out setting up the debugger in Eclipse.

Oh and I downloaded and installed gdb-apple via macports and I had to use the "-f" option with the codesign command as it didn't work without. Maybe these are important information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep using gdb (not gdb-apple) and just do the following steps:

1- Create a certificate:

- Start Keychain Access application (/Applications/Utilities/Keychain Access.app)
- Open menu /Keychain Access/Certificate Assistant/Create a Certificate...
- Choose a name (gdb-cert in the example), set Identity Type to "Self Signed Root", set Certificate Type to "Code Signing" and select the "Let me override defaults".
- Click several times on Continue until you get to the Specify a Location For The Certificate screen, then set Keychain to System.
- Using the contextual menu for the certificate, select "Get Info", open the Trust item, and set Code Signing to "Always Trust".

2- You must quit Keychain Access application (named "taskgated",from activity monitor) and open it again in order to use the certificate.

3- Assign the certificate to gdb:

- using the following command: `$ codesign -s gdb-cert gdb`

For more details, check this link:
http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin

if any of these steps are not clear, feel free to ask.

Comment: Worked for me on OS X Yosemite. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This may happen if you signed 'gdb' before making all changes to 'gdb-cert'. Then you can restart 'taskgated' and then re-sign the 'gdb' executable.

1. ps -e | grep taskgated
2. sudo kill -9 <pid of taskgated>
3. codesign -f -s gdb-cert $(which gdb)

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you get this below error, don't forget to add `sudo` in front of the command:

`sudo codesign -s gdb-cert $(which gdb-apple)`

`codesign -s gdb-cert $(which gdb-apple)`

```
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate: can't create output file: /opt/local/bin/gdb-apple.cstemp (Permission denied)
/opt/local/bin/gdb-apple: the codesign_allocate helper tool cannot be found or used
```