# eclipse cdt on mac osx not showing debug menu in preference set

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, debugging, eclipse-cdt

I'm using eclipse with CDT on mac osx mavericks. I've installed gdb using macports. But I'm not able to set custom debugger in preference set.
When I go to preferrnce->c++->Debug->? there is no debug option where I can set custom debugger. Online eclipse CDT documentation suggest debug menu in this preference set. I've tried Kepler as well as Luna but still issue persist.

I'm not sure what's wrong with my eclipse. Please help. Thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYD9A.png

Answer (score 2):

Open "Debug Configurations" from the debugging icon, then choose Debugger tab and specify the gdb command path "e.g. /usr/local/bin/gdb"

After that you have to give gdb permission to control other processes, follow steps mentioned in the reply of this question:
[debugging in eclipse using gdb on mac - Failed to execute MI command: -exec-run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640787/debugging-in-eclipse-using-gdb-on-mac-failed-to-execute-mi-command-exec-run/29451056#29451056)